# How can i get username in oauth 2 token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, access-token

Im trying to get user properties from oauth2 token, using login microsoft request, but i just get the email in token claims. Is there a way to get the username in token claims?

This is the complete request:
[image: Postman request]

Comment: Could you confirm whether your ask is to retrieve this b2c [username](https://i.imgur.com/ztgzdAn.png) in token claims?

Comment: yes, get username in token claims.

Comment: To get username in token claims, you can either create custom attribute or switch to custom policies. Check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/765324/how-to-get-the-signin-name(username)-as-a-claims-a

Comment: Can I post answer by creating custom attribute to get username in token claims? Will it satisfy your requirement?

Comment: If that custom attribute is the username, using that request, then yes, it will.

Comment: Do you want to get access token using ROPC flow only? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: I didn't know this, maybe this token is what i need if retrieve the username.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256095/discussion-between-sridevi-and-pedro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I created one **custom** attribute named `username` in my B2C tenant like this:

[image]

In your Sign Up and Sign In flow, make sure to include **`username`** attribute before running it:

[image]

When new user is signing up, it will ask the user to enter the **username** again like this:

[image]

Before generating token using ROPC flow, make sure to include **`username`** in **Application claims** like this:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://<b2ctenant_name>.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_ROPC_Auth/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:password
client_id: appId
scope:openid <appId> offline_access
username: <username>
password:xxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded this token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website, I got **username** in token claims successfully like this:

[image]

**Reference:**

[How to get the signin-name(username) as a claims after login - Microsoft Q&A by **AmanpreetSingh-MSFT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/765324/how-to-get-the-signin-name(username)-as-a-claims-a)